# Kotlin function as val expression

Tags: kotlin

I declared a function expression as a val:

```
val greeting = {
  println("what the hello1")
  println("what the hello2")
}
```

Then, I'd like to call it like this:

```
greeting
```

However, nothing is printing when I call it.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that Kotlin expressions need to be called with parenthesis like this:
`greeting()`
or `greeting.invoke()`

Comment: More precisely `greeting` as you defined it is a function ( of type `Function0<Unit>` or `() -> Unit `) and as such needs to be called with `()`